# Cauchy formula for repeated Lebesgue integration

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral

Is there an equivalent of the Cauchy formula for repeated integration (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_formula_for_repeated_integration) for the following

\begin{equation}
f^{(-n)}(x) = \int_a^x \int_a^{\sigma_1} \cdots \int_a^{\sigma_{n-1}} f(\sigma_{n}) \, \mathrm{d}g(\sigma_{n}) \cdots \, \mathrm{d}g(\sigma_2) \, \mathrm{d}g(\sigma_1)
\end{equation}

Comment: $g$ is a measure?

Comment: maybe this helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/97182/cauchy-formula-for-repeated-lebesgue-integration

Comment: yes, it's a measure